# Error when parsing a valid JSON file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following text in the file "lineValuesJSON.json".

```
{"4": {"0": {"0": {"0": {"0": [0, 0, 0, 0]}}}}}
```

I load this file in HTML via

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/moveRating/lineValuesJSON.json"></script>
```

and parse it then in Javascript with

```
const lineValues = JSON.parse(lineValuesJSON);
```

I get the following error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

I have checked the json code on https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, it says that it is valid. Does anyone know why I get this error?

Comment: you cannot load JSON as JS.

Answer (score 0):

JSON isn't JavaScript. `text/javascript` is the wrong MIME type for JSON. JSON is not a script. `<script>` elements don't create variables named after the file name of the script loaded. You can't use a `<script>` element to load JSON.

If you want to load JSON from a URL, request it using the `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` APIs.